# Python if evaluation and an or statement. Two trues not evaulating to true

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I'm working on this leetcode problem:

```
class Solution:
    def isSameTree(self, q, p):

        print(q != None)
        print(not p)
        if q != None and not p:
            return False
        
        if q and p:
            if q.val == p.val:
                self.isSameTree(q.left, p.left)
                self.isSameTree(q.right, p.right)
        
        return True
```

Input: q = [1,2]
p = [1,null,2]

Output from run:

```
True
False
True
True
False
False
```

You can see that in the second run, `q != None` evaluates to true and `not p` evaluates to true, but the if statement is not returning false. What is happening here??

Comment: the if statement is probably returning false, but it's one layer deep in your recursion. if you want that false condition to exit you from your program or print to the console then you need to either do "print(self.isSameTree(q.left, p.left)" or "if self.isSameTree(q.left, p.left): return false"

Answer (score 0):

You probably just never print your return so it return False but you dont see it.